# Why is Fscrawler refusing to trust certificate while I have set ssl verification to 'false"?

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler

Here's my Yaml file for fscrawler:

---

```
name: "data_science"
fs:
  url: "C:\\tmp\\DS_books"
  update_rate: "15m"
  excludes:
  - "*/~*"
  json_support: false
  filename_as_id: false
  add_filesize: true
  remove_deleted: true
  add_as_inner_object: false
  store_source: false
  index_content: true
  attributes_support: false
  raw_metadata: false
  xml_support: false
  index_folders: true
  lang_detect: false
  continue_on_error: false
  ocr:
    language: "eng"
    enabled: true
    pdf_strategy: "ocr_and_text"
  follow_symlinks: false
elasticsearch:
  nodes:
  - url: "https://127.0.0.1:9200"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "8u4c0pEXmjYwq_Pd4zeX"
  bulk_size: 100
  flush_interval: "5s"
  byte_size: "10mb"
  ssl_verification: false
```

Yet I get the following message when I try to build index:

"WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-0MS6MUS] http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:51966}"

Answer (score 1):

replaced with most recent Elasticsearch 8.4.3 and problem isn't occurring anymore...

Comment: Thanks for giving a closure on this. BTW, which version of FSCrawler are you using?

Comment: Sorry David don't remember